# How long can I purchase a expired domain name?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

I am currently interested in a domain name. Its whois information are

> Updated Date: 10-jan-2012
>
> Creation Date: 1-dec-2010
>
> Expiration Date: 1-dec-2011

How long I still need to wait to purchase this domain name freely as it is a unregistered domain name?

What's the 'updated date'?

What's the usual steps for an expired domain name?

Comment: Hmm, normally, the expiration date should be *past* the *updated* date. It looks like this domain’s registration ended Dec.01.2011 and was left lapsing for over a month and was renewed/purchased on Jan.10.2012. In that case, the expiration date should be updated at some point to Jan.10.201x depending on the lease length. Try using a different whois provider to see if they have a more up-to-date record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How long I still need to wait to purchase this domain name freely as it is a unregistered domain name?

Grace periods differ from registrar to registrar. Usually for expired domains I can see also free-date string.

> What's the 'updated date'?

Date of last changes of data or date of your request: in, f.e "Last updated on 2012.02.24 03:06:00 MSK/MSD"  date-time is *request time*.